# How to get the location of the component of a window in Linux?

Tags: linux, x11

In Linux, one can use `xwininfo` to get the location of a window. Is that possible to get the location of it's component, e.g. the content area of a browser, the button of a window? `-children` option of `xwininfo` can only get the location of children windows, not components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that modern toolkits (like GTK+, Qt) *do not* necessarily back every component with an X11 window, but I find it hard to find a definite source for this claim. If the components, or *widgets*, are not backed by X11 windows, `xwininfo` will not be able to determine their location.

For example, GTK+ used to interpret the environment variable `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS` to mean that every GdkWindow ([corresponding to every widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkWindow)) should have a native window, but this was only for compatability with some applications that would not work otherwise. This feature has since been removed (https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2011-March/msg03590.html). Gtk+/Gdk now has [gtk_ensure_native_window()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-ensure-native), but if not enabled explicitly by the programmer, it seems that Gdk will not back the widgets by X11 windows and therefore `xwininfo` will not be able to pick up the location of these.

It seems that there may be alternatives for specific toolkits though. For example, GTK+ has [gtkparasite](http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/05/15/introducing-gtkinspector/) which might be able to give you the information on specific components, but this will only work for GTK+ applications.